# No header and footer in no chapter pages

Tags: header-footer

I wrote a LaTeX code for my project. I used fancyhf for footers and headers. But there's no header and footer in the pages without chapters.

There's my code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
includehead,
nomarginpar,
headheight=10mm,
left=20mm,
right=20mm,
top=15mm,
headsep=0mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext,calc,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf[LH]{\Huge \fontseries{sb}\selectfont Headerer title\\\scriptsize Header text}
\fancyhf[RH]{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{logo.png}}
\fancyhf[FC]{\includegraphics[height=7pt]{logo.png} Footer title \\ Footer text}
\fancyhf[RF]{\thepage}}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]
\section{new section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{another section}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test de}
\lipsum[1] 
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test de}
\lipsum[2] 
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test de}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Invoke the style fancy with `\pagestyle{fancy}`

Comment: @SimonDispa Then it uses the default "fancy" setting in that pages, section on the left and chapter on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I changed the `\fancypagestyle{fancy}` with same configurations, moved the fancyhfs outside to document, and added `\pagestyle{fancy}` in document.

Added section:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf[LH]{\Huge \fontseries{sb}\selectfont Headerer title\\\scriptsize Header text}
\fancyhf[RH]{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{logo.png}}
\fancyhf[FC]{\includegraphics[height=7pt]{logo.png} Footer title \\ Footer text}
\fancyhf[RF]{\thepage}}
```

The solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
includehead,
nomarginpar,
headheight=10mm,
left=20mm,
right=20mm,
top=15mm,
headsep=0mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext,calc,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf[LH]{\Huge \fontseries{sb}\selectfont Headerer title\\\scriptsize Header text}
\fancyhf[RH]{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{logo.png}}
\fancyhf[FC]{\includegraphics[height=7pt]{logo.png} Footer title \\ Footer text}
\fancyhf[RF]{\thepage}}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
\fancyhf[LH]{\Huge \fontseries{sb}\selectfont Headerer title\\\scriptsize Header text}
\fancyhf[RH]{\includegraphics[height=10mm]{logo.png}}
\fancyhf[FC]{\includegraphics[height=7pt]{logo.png} Footer title \\ Footer text}
\fancyhf[RF]{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]
\section{new section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{another section}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test de}
\lipsum[1] 
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test de}
\lipsum[2] 
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test de}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question but can you give some more detail about what you did, ideally with a short example people can compile to see how it works?

Comment: @cfr Of course, edited!

Comment: @Hangear, you were asked for MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which can be tested as it is. You provide only code fragment ...